# Geting "is not marked as serializable." exception while serializing the class which is derived from System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use cache the claim object of each logged in user. But i am getting the above exception when i am trying to serialize the object. I am using Newtonsoft.json package for serialize and deserialize.

Comment: Not totally sure about this but I think that the ClaimsPrincipal object may have private or protected properties or classes which I do not think are serializable

Comment: I can't reproduce this for an empty `ClaimsPrincipal`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sjmmyg.  You, however, are using a *class which is derived from System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal*, so can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?